# Weighted clustering of tags

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, data-mining

I have a list of products and each product is tagged and weights associated to it each tag. Now I want to cluster them into similar products. How do I go forward it. I have tried k-means of scikit-learn. But That is not helping much.

```
Product 1: a=2.5 b=3.5 c=1 d=1
Product 2: a=0.25 c=2
Product 3: e=2 k=5
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
Product n: a=3 b=0.75
```

Now I want these to be clustered. I also want a product to be in many clusters if necessary. Because 1, 2, 3 can form a cluster and 2, 4, 5 can form other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [Gaussian Mixture Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_model#Gaussian_mixture_model) which can be seen as a generalisation of k-means which allows soft clusters. You can have K clusters, and each entry belongs to all clusters with a certain amount. This amount is the probability of the entry under that cluster.
Luckily there is [scikit-learn code](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/mixture.html) for this.

You can treat the set of tags across all products as defining a feature space for the entries. The presence of a tag on a product means that product will have a non-zero entry, equal to the weight, in the position corresponding to that tag. From there, you have a fixed vector to describe entries and GMMs can be applied.

---

However, it is really hard to evaluate unsupervised learning approaches like this. Rather, you should evaluate methods in light of the downstream task they are used for. like suggesting products to people or detecting fraud or detecting duplicates etc.

Answer (score 1):

If the direct and naïve application of k-means is *not helping much*, you may need to dig a bit deeper.

Assuming you have `N` distinct tags of which `0..N` can be applied to each product `p`. Each assignment describes a weighted relationship with a positive weight `w`. Absence of a tag for a product equals `w = 0`.

This is your setup that yields an `N`-dimensional feature space for your products. You should be able to use arbitrary clustering methods; you *just* have to select the correct measures.

**Your distance (or similarity) measure should depend on your data.**

Consequently, the first thing to ask yourself is: When are two measures considered *similar*?

- If they have as many overlapping tags as possible?
- If the sum of differences between non-overlapping tag weights is max?
- If the sum of differences between overlapping tags is min?
- ...

Depending on your defined *similarity*, you should be able to choose or implement a measure that yields the grade of similarity (not just the euclidean distance in `N` dimensions) when comparing two elements.

Also, you may want to check [this post at CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3713/choosing-clustering-method) or (if you want to learn more about clustering) [Section 7.3](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/mmds/ch7.pdf) of *"Mining of Massive Datasets"* (2014, Anand Rajaraman, Jure Leskovec, and Jeffrey D. Ullman) [[Entire book](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/mmds/book.pdf)]